# form rendering in django

Tags: django, forms

I am new to HTML and django
I have created a form in django as

```
existing_rsets = Set.objects.all()
choices_int = tuple((p.name, p.name) for p in existing_rsets)
region_set = forms.ChoiceField(label='Set, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),choices=choices_int,required=False)
```

How do I render the form in template and later get that in code. Please provide example code.

Comment: Please provide example code of what you have tried

Comment: Do you try to read the [official form doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple example.

**1) app/forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class PersonForm(forms.Form):

    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('', '----------'),
        ('MALE', 'Male'),
        ('FEMALE', 'Female'),
    )

    MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('', '----------'),
        ('SINGLE', 'Single'),
        ('MARRIED', 'Married'),
    )

    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First name', max_length=255)
    middle_name = forms.CharField(label='Middle name', max_length=255)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last name', max_length=255)
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(label='Gender', choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    martial_status = forms.ChoiceField(label='Martial status', choices=MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES)
```

**2) app/views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import PersonForm

def person(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PersonForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/some-url/xyz')
    else:
        form = PersonForm()

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'app/templates/person.html', context)
```

**3) app/templates/person.html**

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    {{ field.label_tag }}
    {{ field }}
    <span style='color:red'>{{ field.errors.as_text }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

Read more on Django forms [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/).

Comment: Thanks for the details. It really helped